# Modelling Technique Question

Tags: modeling

I'm following a time lapse clip which has to do modelling the PLayStation 5.
I cant seem to understand what the modeller is doing at 0:20 seconds,(**I lowered the speed at 0.25**) Somehow he is avoid a tri face. But If I continue modelling, as seen from the different angles I've provided I'll get a tri face in the corner of my model. Can someone please tell me what he's doing with the mesh to get a quad when he extrudes the mesh.

Thank you.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WzGkQAfxakE&list=LLZ2XZXqOZRx6idQLEh4-RIw&index=2&t=13s

[image]

Comment: I think he simply makes so the right edge of the rectangle is shared with the side part on the right. See the result at https://youtu.be/WzGkQAfxakE?t=26 and following

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the video he had some hesitations but at some step the result is simply to merge two vertices.

In vertex selection mode <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>,

Select the vertex on the left, then <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the other one.

Then merge them using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> then *'At last'*.

The model is more or less in this situation:

[image]

Comment: Whoa, thanks for that demo, this really clarified any doubts I had!